# How to use dlply to run function for two or more grouping variables in R?

Tags: r, plyr

I want to use `dlply` in the `plyr` package to subset my data by more than one attribute/variable.

With the function `aggregate` for several variables, the syntax is : `by=list(data$var1, data$var2)`.  What is the equivalent in `dlply`?

For example, using `aggregate`, I would use the following syntax:

```
data(meuse)
aggregate(meuse[,3:7], by=list(meuse$landuse, meuse$dist.m), FUN=mean)
#    Group.1 Group.2   cadmium   copper     lead     zinc      elev
#1        Ah      10  7.500000 56.50000 167.5000  727.500  7.640000
#2        Fw      10  8.300000 77.00000 158.0000  761.000  7.360000
#3         W      10  9.800000 89.11111 299.7778 1090.222  7.449111
#4         W      20  9.075000 81.75000 263.0000 1009.750  6.909000
#5        Ah      30  8.600000 81.00000 277.0000 1141.000  6.983000
#6         W      40  2.700000 27.00000 124.0000  375.000  8.261000
#7        Ah      50 11.700000 85.00000 299.0000 1022.000  7.909000
#8         W      50 18.100000 76.00000 464.0000 1672.000  7.307000
#9        Ah      60  2.400000 47.00000 297.0000  832.000  8.809000
#10       Am      60  7.900000 67.00000 217.0000  833.000  7.784000
```

Here's the example with only one variable.

```
library(plyr)
#one way of calling attribute name
dlply(meuse, "landuse", function (x) lm(x$copper~x$lead))
#another way of calling attribute name
dlply(meuse, as.quoted(.(landuse)), function (x) lm(x$copper~x$lead))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this question, I explored the questions that pop up on the side, which helped me figure out the syntax for `dplyr` better. And I found the solution to my question by trial and error but no previous question actually resolved my issue specifically, so here's the simple answer to what I was struggling with.

My original syntax with quotations ("") around the attribute name did not seem to work for multiple attributes. The attribute/variable name can be between `.(`and close `)`, and then two attributes/variables can be used.

```
library(plyr)
data(meuse)
dlply(meuse, as.quoted(.(landuse, dist.m)), function (x) lm(x$copper~x$lead))
#as.quoted seems to be optional, this works too
dlply(meuse, .(landuse, dist.m), function (x) lm(x$copper~x$lead))
```